# Javascript Variable Does Not Retain Value

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to return the response from an AJAX call from a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call-from-a-function)

I have a function that reads numerical data from a file online. While the file is retrieved correctly (proven by the value displayed by the alert), when I try to set it to output and then return output, I get an undefined result.

I tried to go through scoping tutorials to no avail. What am I doing wrong?

```
function readFileFromWeb() {
    var output;

    jQuery.get('http://domain.com', function(data) {
        alert(data);
        output = data;
    });

    return output;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of **async**! You can't do that.

Comment: @FelixKling: I was shocked for a moment when I saw your name under that question... ;/

Comment: 2 approaches to do what you want here:
1) make you AJAX synchronous
2) implement a timer based functionality that will wait for the response to assign value to a variable you want to use.

Comment: @MarcellFülöp Both approaches are awful. I'd recommend understanding and embracing asynchronicity.

Comment: @bfavarett I don't think I miss anything about understanding async... What approach would you come up with for _returning_ value from ajax callback?

Comment: @MarcellFülöp I was not talking about you, I am talking about recommending that to others. If people don't understand async, I recommend they understand it first. The way to go is to not return, and pass/use a callback instead. Or return a promise.

Comment: @bfavarett You're right in that.. I wasn't arguing how much one understands the concept of async, just recommending a solution for the problem of returning from (A)JAX. I write quite complex JS applications using lots of AJAX and in some (rare) cases, my best choice is making it sync.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how it should be done, via a callback function.

```
function readFileFromWeb(callback) {
    jQuery.get('http://domain.com', function(data) {
        callback && callback(data);
    });
}

// ...

readFileFromWeb(function (data) {
    alert(data);
});
```

This is because `jQuery.get` is an asynchronous function i.e. it doesn't block while executing and thus returns immediately.  And that is infact the reason why the `jQuery.get` function requires a callback function, so that it fires your callback function once the AJAX query has returned.

Thus, you will need to use the same callback pattern when implementing your own `readFileFromWeb` function.

Comment: Could you describe what that does `callback && callback(data);`? Callback is executed if it's passed as parameter,isn't it?

Comment: Yup, I'm using the short-circuiting mechanism employed in the logical operators to only invoke `callback` if it contains a truthy value.  Note though that this code will still fail if `callback` is not a function because I'm not validating that.

Comment: I see, 10x for sharing that

Comment: Thanks for the insightful comments, everyone!

If I understand correctly:
1. I call readFileFromWeb with a function (to do something with the result) as parameter.
2. readFileFromWeb executes the async get, then calls callback, which is the anonymous function we defined.

Is this correct?

Comment: @KangHeong: Yes.  Also keep in mind that the `readFileFromWeb` function returns immediately since `jQuery.get` returns immediately.

Answer (score 1):

It's async, I've commented your code to help you understand the order in which things are happening.

```
function readFileFromWeb() {
    //1. create variable.
    var output;

    //2. make ajax call.
    jQuery.get('http://domain.com', function(data) {
        alert(data);

        //4. set variable from ajax callback
        output = data;
    });

    //3. return variable.
    return output;
}
```

Comment: +1 for listing down the evaluation order.